# View Custom Tizen WatchFace in Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I am trying to run the SDK sample Watch Face in the Emulator but I get some cryptic message:

```
Certain application categories, such as "Watch Application", cannot be launched by "Run As"
```

I have been Google digging without success for couple of days, including Tizen developer site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error message. 
Because the watch application is a kind of widget application, you need to set the look of watch with setting menu. 
The tizen sdk just install the watch application to the emulator and the real launching can be triggered by the watchface setting.

Comment: You got me in the right direction. If you swipe the emulator face upwards you get to change settings. The new face was hidden in "Clock". My assumption was that the Bezel would take care of things. Thanks!

Comment: I kept thinking it was an error message but it's definitely not. Just wasn't looking in the right place. Thanks!